# Integrating web application with DSC card

Tags: java, digital-signature, smartcard, digital-certificate

I am working on a new application where I have a requirement to use the end-user digital card to sign a document which is being uploaded in the application. I will be creating a Java/J2EE based application. Now the question is that how do I get the information of the digital signature in my web application. The end-user will plug in the USB DSC card on his/her system and that is to be used for signing the document.

How can my web application interact with the digital certificates present in the end user system?

I have no idea on how this can be done, however I have seen web application where the application asks for the certificate to be used for signing and that certificates are picked up from the user system.

I searched over net but didn't get any solution or pointer for this. Any pointers on any documentation will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write java applet which will interact with the card on the client side. In most cases such applets can use [Sun PKCS#11 provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) to create signature with signing keys stored on smartcard. Similar applet is developed as a part of [Digital Signature Service](https://code.google.com/p/sd-dss/) open source project.

Comment: Jariq - Thanks for your comment, however, I am not able to understand on how I can get digital certificates from a windows machine. Can you please elaborate on your point.

Comment: @Ankit you can use [SunMSCAPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI) provider to read certificates from Windows certificate store.

Comment: FYI you could use JavaFX instead of an older applet (such as a Swing applet) but not as many users may have the capability to run JavaFX installed in their browsers.